# Custom Python CSV delimiter

Tags: python, csv

How to ignore commas in between double quotes and remove commas that are not between double quotes?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  I think it would help if you provided some examples of the input format and what you want to get.

Comment: Hopefully you are using [a proper csv parser](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) and not attempting to parse this manually.

Comment: Michael, this was an exercise, that was wanting to parse lines of text into csv format.  I ended up using the csv module.  I'm still interested in a way to work it out with out the module though.

Comment: For anyone who reads this question hoping for a way to read "custom delimited" value files, like "tab-separated", "`|`-separated", "`$`-separated", and so on, know that the `csv` module allows you to specify a custom delimiter: `csv.reader(file, delimiter="$")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batteries are included - simply use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) that comes with Python.

Example:

```
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = r"/your/file/path/here.csv"
    file_handle = open(file_path, "r")
    csv_handle = csv.reader(file_handle)
    # Now you can work with the *values* in the csv file.
```

Comment: I did end up using the csv module.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for your interest, you *can* (mostly) do this using regular expressions;

```
mystr = 'No quotes,"Quotes",1.0,42,"String, with, quotes",1,2,3,"",,""'
import re
csv_field_regex = re.compile("""
(?:^|,)         # Lookbehind for start-of-string, or comma
(
    "[^"]*"     # If string is quoted: match everything up to next quote
    |
    [^,]*       # If string is unquoted: match everything up to the next comma
)
(?=$|,)         # Lookahead for end-of-string or comma
""", re.VERBOSE)

m = csv_field_regex.findall(mystr)

>>> pprint.pprint(m)
['No quotes',
 '"Quotes"',
 '1.0',
 '42',
 '"String, with, quotes"',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '""',
 '',
 '""']
```

This handles everything except escaped quote marks appearing inside quoted strings. It's possible to handle this case too, but the regex gets nastier; this is why we have the `csv` module.

Comment: -1 The quoted strings should be returned without the enclosing quotes. Also this presumes that the user is responsible for splitting up the input file into rows; a tad difficult when there are newlines in the data.

Comment: @JohnMachin: If you're parsing csv with regex, you have bigger issues than this anyway. ;)

Comment: **YOU** are the one who's parsing csv with regex. I can't imagine why you wrote that answer at all. "Mostly" == "FAIL".

Comment: Using regex came to mind, being completely new to CSV. Thanks!